# Getting parts of markdown files in Jekyll

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

**Question:** With Jekyll is it possible to display part of a markdown file in a template file?
I would want to do this in order to avoid using `div`'s in my markdown, I have some elements that need styling and if you put `div`'s in markdown then anything in them will not be marked down(if you add markdown="1" it just adds a grey box around the text). So to get around this I want to capture some text like so:

```
{% capture workshops %}
    ![Suitcase]({{ site.url }}/img/icons/suitcase.png)
    **Proffesional Workshops**
    Brief description of workshops, more detailed description 
    of workshops will go on seperate dedicated page.
{% endcapture %}
```

and then somehow put this markdown in the layout page maybe like this?

```
<div class="feature">
    {{ page.workshops }}
</div>
```

Is this possible? or is there a better way of getting around using `div`'s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [excerpts](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#post_excerpts).

Quote from the link:

> Each post automatically takes the first block of text, from the
>   beginning of the content to the first occurrence of `excerpt_separator`,
>   and sets it as the `post.excerpt`. Take the above example of an index of
>   posts. Perhaps you want to include a little hint about the post’s
>   content by adding the first paragraph of each of your posts:
>
> ```
> <ul>
>   {% for post in site.posts %}
>     <li>
>       <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
>       <p>{{ post.excerpt }}</p>
>     </li>
>   {% endfor %}
> </ul>
> ```

---

I'm not sure if you need this for blog posts or for actual pages.
The above quote is from the documentation about **blog posts**, but apparently every **page** has the `.excerpt` property, according to the documentation about [variables](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#page_variables).
*(I didn't try it with a page, though)*